# Is it possible to tail both file and journalctl using the same console?

Tags: tail, journaling

I am looking for a solution for tailing not only multiple files in parallel but also the `journalctl`.

Multitail seems to do a pretty good job but I don't know a way to make it work with journalctl.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read, multitail can use stdin as a file. Just use `-j` where you would like stdin to be read.

Journalctl can output data as `tail -f` would using the `-f` option so something like `journalctl -f | multitail file1 -j file2` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem repeatedly and have put together a script: https://github.com/gjedeer/journaltail/blob/main/journaltail

```
journaltail -u apache2.service -u nginx /var/log/messages
```